# Is it ok to ask "What is the point of this guys question"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, title

I'm in a little bit counfused situation on asking a question on Stackoverflow or not. So I'm here first. I'm reading a programming book now. One of the helpers on this book asking a question in this book and I didn't understand this question why asked in it and what is the answer. And I want to ask it on Stackoverflow but I'm not sure how can I ask it wihtout close vote or delete vote. What should be the correct way to ask it? I have a few idea:

- What is the point of [authors_name] question in [book_name]?
- [Copy the question title in book] Example: **Why there is a var keyword?**
- Why [authors_name] asking [questions_title] ?

Or any better solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a suggestion (doesn't mean it won't be closed by the community, but I think it should stand up to the test):

Let's say that a book author suggested that C# doesn't actually support generics:

> Question title: Why doesn't C# support generics?
>
> According to Tiny Tim, the author of C# Out of Depth, C# doesn't
>   actually support generics:
>
> `<blockquote containing evidence from book, with bibliographical
>   citation>`
>
> My question is, why is he saying this when it is so demonstrably
>   wrong? (With evidence or link that it's demonstrably wrong)

Now, it may end up being too localized, or if there isn't code immediately involved, may end being closed as off topic (although it'd probably be on topic for Programmers -- but you didn't hear me say that).

A few pointers:

- Try to keep the question *constructive*. Asking why someone is an idiot is usually *not constructive*. Asking, "They show this evidence, but I believe it's wrong, is it wrong, and if so, why?" is more constructive.
- Keep it on topic. This isn't about their book, this is really about programming a particular feature.  Their book should be used as evidence, but that should not be the central focus of the question.
- Try not to get too upset if your question gets closed.  All too often, people get angry that their question gets closed, and they react angrily -- and usually lose any and all support because of their angry outbursts.  Some of the best questions in Stack Overflow's history have had a contentious existence.

Suggestion, don't ask the one about `var`. [It's already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp).